# Leaflet: Markers hidden when panning map

Tags: leaflet

I've implemented a Leaflet map with a couple of different custom markers using DivIcons.

It works fine in desktop browsers, but when I pan the map on a mobile device the markers that aren't currently visible in the viewport seems to be hidden until I stop panning the map.

Is there any option for disabling this behavior? I would ideally like to keep the markers rendered all the time.

I should mention that I'm using the MarkerCluster plugin as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is the effect of Leaflet.markercluster plugin [`removeOutsideVisibleBounds`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#enabled-by-default-boolean-options) option.

On desktop, it keeps markers and clusters within the viewport + 1 extra viewport in each direction.

On mobile it keeps them only for the visible viewport.

See also https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/issues/316

You can modify the lines at https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster/blob/master/src/MarkerClusterGroup.js#L1071-L1079 to suit your need:

```js
L.MarkerClusterGroup.include({
  _getExpandedVisibleBounds: function() {
    /*if (!this.options.removeOutsideVisibleBounds) {
      return this._mapBoundsInfinite;
    } else if (L.Browser.mobile) {
      return this._checkBoundsMaxLat(this._map.getBounds());
    }*/

    // Always return the current viewport extended by 1 extra viewport in each direction.
    return this._checkBoundsMaxLat(this._map.getBounds().pad(1)); // Padding expands the bounds by its own dimensions but scaled with the given factor.
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! removeOutsideVisibleBounds was exactly what I was looking for.